# Chamar um arquivo HTML dentro de um modal Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, modal, lightbox

O caso é o seguinte:

Uso o Modal Lightbox para uma galeria de imagens, no index tenho os thumbs e ao clicar abre o modal com a imagem maximizada.

Devido a quantidade de imagens demora muito para carregar todas.

Como posso chamar um arquivo html contendo as imagens para dentro do modal da index? Assim não carregaria essas imagens ao carregar a index.

```js
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_nature.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_fjords.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_lights.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="Nature and sunrise">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="Mountains and fjords">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="http://www.lsphotografia.com/modal/img_lights_wide.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="Northern Lights">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode usar um `<iframe>`, mas no geral daria para resolver isto com um pre-loader e nem precisaria de iframes, só não consigo fornecer um exemplo, porque teu script não funciona e por este motivo não sei por onde começar para modificar ele assim.

Comment: Editei o código e está funcionando, estava sem o endereço completo das imagens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como havia me pedido HTML:

```
<div id="abremodal" class="btn btn-primary " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#minhaModal">Open Modal</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="minhaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div id="conteudoModal">
                      nada
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#abremodal").click(function(){
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "endereco_da_sua_pagina_html.html"
        });

        request.done(function (data) {
            $("#conteudoModal").html(data);
        });

        request.fail(function () {
            console.log("Ocorreu um erro na requisição");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Guilherme, agradeço muito a ajuda, mas não consegui fazer funcionar, adicionei seu script mas não carrega o html, exibe as imagens, mas ao clicar abre o modal sem nada.

Comment: Abre o console "F12" e diz qual o erro que aparece. (Lembre-se que meu exemplo eu uso bootstrap e jQuery como api, você precisa adapta-lo para seu modal e incluir o jQuery no seu HTML)

Comment: Já tenho o JQuery incluído   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>, mas não consegui adaptar seu script no html. Continua abrindo o modal vazio, o problema deve ser como mencionou, não consegui adaptá-lo corretamente.

Comment: Guelherme, boa tarde tentei novamente aqui e sem sucesso, se não for pedir muito poderia tentar adaptar seu script no html que postei, ajudaria muito.

Answer (score 0):

Crie uma div com um id dentro do modal e no javascript coloque:

```
$("#SEU_MODAL").click(function(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "SUAPAGINA.html"
    });

    request.done(function (data) {
        $("#ID_DIV_MODAL").html(data);
    });

    request.fail(function () {
        console.log("Ocorreu um erro na requisição");
    });
});
```

Comment: Bom dia Guilherme Biancardi, Não funcionou, o modal abre sem nada, não carrega o html

Comment: Bom dia, fiz o teste aqui e funcionou perfeitamente, verifique se a biblioteca jQuery esta no escopo do seu projeto, e certifique-se que o id #SEU_MODAL seja do botão que faz o modal abrir não o id do modal.

Comment: Guilherme o modal é aberto na função onclick onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" que faz referencia ao id myModal dentro do javascript. Você poderia detalhar como fez para funcionar postando o seu script completo?

Comment: Boa tarde Guilherme, poderia tirar uma dúvida?

Estou utilizando o script da forma que passou e estou tentando fazer o seguinte, após a função ser chamada e carregar o arquivo externo, no caso o get.html e precisava que ao clicar em outro link o conteúdo que foi carregado fosse descartado para carregar um novo. É possível implementar isso nesse script?

Ex: Clica para chamar o get.html, o conteúdo é carregado em seguida clica para chamar o pic.html o get.html é descartado e é carregado o pic.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, utilizei o script passado pelo Guilherme Biancardi, ao invés de chamar o html dentro do modal coloquei um botão chamando o html com o modal completo, ficou perfeito.

Caso queira conferir o endereço é http://gabifez12.lsphotografia.com

Agradeço muito pela ajuda.